# Chunk compressing outgoing request

Tags: java, request, compression, put

I am sending a PUT streaming request and want to

1. send in chunks
2. compress my payload

For smaller payloads, I will just compress the entire payload, then chunk the data. (which seems to be the standard way).

For larger payloads, I want to chunk, compress, then send individually compressed chunks. (to avoid waiting for compression of the entire payload).

What should the format of each chunk look like? I had assumed each compressed chunk needs to follow the regular chunk format with a length + CRLF header, and a CRLF trailer.

What I'm currently doing:

```
byte[] streamingPayload; // data to be streamed
byte[] uncompressedChunk = createChunk(streamingPayload);
byte[] compressedChunk = compressChunk(uncompressedChunk);
```

My chunk looks like:

```
compressedChunk.length CRLF
compressedChunk CRLF
```

However, when testing on Wiremock, I'm getting the error:
`java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format`

Then, I tried compressing the entire chunk with the header/trailer:
i.e., compress this chunk:

```
uncompressedChunk.length CRLF
uncompressedChunk CRLF
```

But still seeing the same error. What am I doing wrong, and what's the right approach to compress in chunks, rather than compressing the payload and then chunking?